# UILocalNotification not using the correct timezone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am configuring my UILocalNotification to use the default timezone i.e. the one in settings of the iPhone i.e. the time that appears on the iPhone's clock however it keeps using greenwich time.  Any ideas?

//This method gets called every time the user changes the event date:

```
- (void)rescheduleNotification {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    //create new one using interval
    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];

    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.fireDate = [self.currentSetting.lessonStartDate dateWithOffsetMinutes:[self.currentSetting.lessonRemindMinutes intValue]];

    NSLog(@"locationNotificated scheduled for %@", localNotification.fireDate);

    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    localNotification.alertAction = nil;
    localNotification.alertBody = @"due to begin shortly";
    localNotification.hasAction = YES;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    [localNotification release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `NSDate` objects when they are printen will use GMT.

So you `NSLog` statement will always display something with the `+0000` timezone.

Example:

if you set the date to `15:00` and your time zone is `+0500` then when you print the date it will say: `10:00` since the offset is `+0500`

Comment: No but it always prints the wrong time regardless of the +0000

Comment: Yes that is correct, since it has calculated the time with the offset.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` is not timezone set in phone preferences, for this You should use

```
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```